# Не срабатывает обработчик события

Tags: javascript, html

Всем привет!

Создал форму с регистром, не получается задействовать event listener..

После заполнения формы и субмита нечего непроисходит.. Буду рад помощи..

```js
 
function registerHandler(user){


  console.log(user.username);
  console.log(user.userid);
  console.log(user.firstname);
  console.log(user.lastname);
  console.log(user.password);
  console.log(user.email);

   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

   xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){

    if(xhr.readyState!=4 && xhr.status!=200){
        return window.alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
   }

    xhr.open("POST","http://localhost:8080/CouponOnWeb/webappl/register",true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/json;charset=utf-8');
    xhr.send(user);
}




function registerController(){

  
   document.getElementById("reg_button").onclick = function(){

    var user = {

    username:document.getElementById("reg_user_name").value,
    firstname:document.getElementById("first_name").value,
    lastname:document.getElementById("last_name").value,
    userid:document.getElementById("user_id").value,
    password:document.getElementById("reg_password").value,
    email:document.getElementById("reg_email").value

    }

  console.log(user.username);
  console.log(user.userid);
  console.log(user.firstname);
  console.log(user.lastname);
  console.log(user.password);
  console.log(user.email);

  registerHandler(user);

   }
 }
```

```html
  <form id = "registrator">
  
  <label for = "reg_user_name">User name:</label>
  <input id = "reg_user_name" name = "reg_user_name" type = "text" placeholder = "user name">
  <br>
  <label for = "first_name">First name:</label>
  <input id = "first_name" name = "first_name" type = "text" placeholder = "first name">
  <br>
  <label for = "last_name">Last name:</label>
  <input id = "last_name" name = "last_name" type = "text" placeholder = "last name">
  <br>
  <label for = "user_id">Id number:</label>
  <input id = "user_id" name = "user_id" type = "number" placeholder = "id number">
  <br>
  <label for = "reg_password">Password:</label>
  <input id = "reg_password" name = "reg_password" type = "text" placeholder = "password">
  <br>
  <label for = "reg_email">Email:</label>
  <input id = "reg_email" name = "reg_email" type = "email" placeholder = "email">
  <br>
  <input id = "reg_button" name = "reg_button" type = "submit" value = "Register" onclick = "registerController()">


  </form>
```

Comment: Поменял. Не работает

Comment: Насчёт Label не понял.. Почему нельзя ?

Comment: С удовольствием приму критику)

Comment: Вынес в ответ ошибки которые видел с ходу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.**   `label for id = "reg_user_name"` -> так нельзя.
Вы фактически присваиваете id лейблу. А у вас еще есть элемент с таким же id.
  Если Вы хотите привязать label к элементу с неким id надо просто:
   `<label for = "reg_user_name">User name:</label>`

**2.** Вы хотите обработчик повесить на всю форму а не кнопку. Вы точно хотите чтобы ваш запрос уходил при каждом клике на любой элемент формы?

**3.**
Вы не отправляете xhr запрос, потому что код отправки запроса написали в обработчике ответа. Вынесите код отправки на фигурную скобку ниже

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(xhr.readyState!=4 && xhr.status!=200){
      return window.alert(xhr.responseText);
  }
}

xhr.open("POST","http://localhost:8080/CouponOnWeb/webappl/register",true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/json;charset=utf-8');
xhr.send(user);
```

Вообще с помощью devtools все эти  ошибки замечаются и правятся за минуту. Учитесь пользоваться инструментами.

Comment: 4. Вы не отправляете xhr запрос, потому что код отправки запроса написали в обработчике ответа.
Где надо писать код отправки запроса ?

Comment: @Maks.Burkov. Вы написали: "когда ответ придет, выполни функцию". Код отправки запроса в этой функции. Соответственно запрос никогда не отправится

Comment: Насчёт вызовов: 
window.onload = function(){

  registerController();
}

Comment: Ок спасибо! Буду учить.

Comment: @Maks.Burkov, ну да, например так

Comment: Насчёт dev tools - ошибок непоказывало с таким кодом)

Comment: @Maks.Burkov, dev tools это не просто штука которая ругается красным когда что-то не так. Вы можете поставить точки остановки программы, посмотреть состояние любой переменной в любой момент, посмотреть приходит ли вообще программа в эту функцию, посмотреть dom дерево и где реально висят какие обработчики. То есть найти момент в котором программа начинает вести себя не так, как Вы ожидали.

Comment: есть где хорошие туториалы для того как пользоватся дебагером ? сколько просмотрел некак не пойму где смотреть значение переменных во время исполнения..

Comment: @Maks.Burkov, http://learn.javascript.ru/debugging-chrome

Comment: Если посмотреть на данный код, который я модифицировал ,
есть ошибки ? так как из того что я вижу их нету и не понятно почему программа не работает

Comment: @Maks.Burkov, одна проблема, один вопрос (читайте правила). Откатите правку и задайте отдельный

Comment: та же тема почти тот же код.. нехотел снова делать  ту же тему